# What are some real-world applications of regular graphs?

Tags: graphs

I've been looking for places where I would find regular graphs in the real world. I know that there are many applications for graphs in general (I've seen this question: [What are some real world applications of graphs?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/126198/what-are-some-real-world-applications-of-graphs)), but I can't find any applications for *regular* graphs. Surprisingly, Google doesn't give me any answers, so I have to resort to asking the experts directly.

It would be great if anyone could give me a couple of examples.